# Combine two keys in Apache Beam

Tags: bigdata, apache-flink, apache-beam, dataflow, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have an Apache Beam streaming project that uses `Combine.perKey()`, I need to be able to merge entities from my admin tool (to point one entity to another one), how to combine two keys with calculated data in Beam? It's easy to do it for the new messages, but how to combine already calculated data?

Comment: What about storing the calculated data into PCollections and then combine them again?

Comment: @JoseGutierrezPaliza, yes, but how to do it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-key the elements before combine so that the calculated data with two keys you want to merge will have same key.

Comment: I need to somehow re-key old data too, not just new records